# Отслеживание прокрутки страницы

Tags: javascript

Как при прокрутки страницы на 1000px(вверх или вниз), выполнить код:

```
        $('.wow').removeClass('animated');
        $('.wow').removeAttr('style');
        new WOW({}).init();
```

Попытка решения(не работает)

```js
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
            if( $(window).scrollTop() <= 50 {
                $('.wow').removeClass('animated');
                $('.wow').removeAttr('style');
                new WOW({}).init();
            }
         });
```

Comment: на 1000рх от какой точки? если я 500рх вниз пролистаю, потом 100рх вверх, потом 600рх снова вниз - скрипт должен сработать? или надо 1000рх за раз? мжб по странице метки расставить, если надо реагировать на какие-нибудь блоки? или скрипт должен срабатывать при преодолении каждого тысячного пикселя сначала страницы?

Comment: На 1000 пикселей от текущей точки, любым способом главное пройти эти 1000 пикселей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если главное это расстояние - тогда Вам нужно измерять разницу между двумя точками, точкой начала скролла и конца. Брать число по модулю и суммировать с предыдущим пробегом.

```
    var distance = 0;
    var prevPos = 0;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
         distance += Math.abs($(window).scrollTop() - prevPos);
         if(distance >= 1000){
            console.log('bingo');
         }
         prevPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Считаем не сколько мы проскроллили, а сравниваем позиции при каждом скроле.

Если разница между изначальной позицией и текущей больше 1000рх, то вызываем метод.

```
var initPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop,
    step = 1000;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (Math.abs(document.documentElement.scrollTop - initPosition) >= step) {
    handler();
  }
});

function handler() {
    console.log(step, 'пройдено');
}
```